# segmentation fault while doing iterative inorder tree traversal

Tags: pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I am doing an iterative search over a binary tree using the stack. But I am getting a segmentation fault. I have crossed checked it many time but couldn't find anything. Please help.

```
void inOrder(struct Node *root) 
{ 
    stack<Node *> s; 
    Node *t;
    s.push(root);

    while (s.empty() == false) { 
        t = s.top();
        while (t->left != NULL) {
            s.push(t->left);
            t = t->left;
        }
        while (1) {
            t = s.top();
            s.pop();
            cout << t->data << " ";
            if (t->right != NULL) {
                s.push(t->right);
                break;
            }
        }
    } /* end of while */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `while(1){`

should be:

```
while (!s.empty()) {
```